# Django - Add products to favorite list

Tags: python, django

I am building a supermarket store, using Django. I have to give user the possibility to add/remove items to/from the Favourite list.
So far i have done the following
models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=1, null=True,
                                 blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    favourites = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourites', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

i created favourites folder and in the folder i have:

views.py

```
def favourites(request, product_id):

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    if product.favourites.filter(id=request.user.ide).exist():
        product.favourites.remove(request.user)
    else:
        product.favourites.add(request.user)
        
    
    return render(request, 'favourites/product_favourite_list.html')


def product_favourite_list(request):
    user=request.user
    favourite_products = user.favourites.all()
    
    context = {
        'favourite_products': favourite_products
    }

    return render(request, 'favourites/product_favourite_list.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.favourites, name='favourites'),
path('favourites/', views.product_favourite_list, name='product_favourite_list'),
```

]

in product_details i have

```
def product_detail(request, product_id):
    """ A view to show individual product details """
    
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    is_favourite = False
    
    if product.favourites.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_favourite = True
    
        
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'is_favourite': is_favourite,
    }

return render(request, 'products/product_detail.html', context)
```

product_details HTML has the following links

```
{% if is_favourite%}
        <a href="{% url 'product_favourite_list' id=product.id %}">
          <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'product_favourite_list' id=product.id %}">
          <i class="far fa-heart fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
      {% endif %}
```

i can see the favourites page. when I click on individual products. I get the error as per the attached snapshot[image: error_message]

Hope somebody can help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide `product.id` to url `product_favourite_list`

> ```
> <a href="{% url 'product_favourite_list' id=product.id %}">
> ```

So you should do:

```
<a href="{% url 'product_favourite_list' %}">
```

You can also adjust **`urlpatterns`**, but I guess it doesn't make sense because you are showing all favourite products of user.

If you should have `id` in `product_favourite_list` add it to the path:

```
path('favourites/<int:id>/', views.product_favourite_list, name='product_favourite_list'),
```

Also add `id` as argument to your view:

```
def product_favourite_list(request, id):
    ...
```